# Неправильная отправка JSON PHP, как избавиться от favicon?

Tags: php, json

[image: Network в браузере]

[image: А вот весь код. index.php]

Сверху Network, снизу код. Как избавиться от favicon.ico, чтобы Vue + axios смогли нормально распарсить эту JSON строку?

Comment: Как связаны vue и favicon.ico?

Comment: Я пробовал читать с других апи таким-же образом, всё нормально, через Network был только json

Comment: favicon тут ни при чем и он подгружается только в браузере. Как отправляете запрос из vue и как парсите?

Comment: @Dantessss в хуке mounted делаю axios.get('example.com').then(response => (this.data = response)); В шаблоне вывожу весь {{ data }}

Comment: И что в response? Давно не пользовался axios, но вроде бы нужно вызвать JSON.parse(response)

Comment: @Dantessss когда обращаюсь к своему - ничего. К другим апи - все данные что запросил

Comment: Попробуйте в опция запроса указать  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

Comment: @Dantessss если я правильно понял, то ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Тогда извиняюсь, но вам нужен человек, который лучше меня разбирается в axios. Я уже больше года использую fetch

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему добавлением такого заголовка: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`